# Update Qt version on ubuntu 16

Tags: qt

I installed qt and qmake is using Qt version on 5.5.1.

```
qmake -v

version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

so how can i update qt version on ubuntu 16 to 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the most recent version available in the repo is 5.5.1.

So the way to go would be to just go to the Qt site and download either the online or the offline installer. You can also get the source and build it yourself, but that's rather slow and not recommended unless you actually need a custom build.

The installer will also give you a maintenance tool you can use to add or remove features and update in the future.